# Disk usage spikes: good, bad or indifferent?

Tags: sql-server, performance, insert

I'm working on a project where we're receiving data from multiple sources, that needs to be saved into various tables in our database.

Fast.

I've played with various methods, and the fastest I've found so far is using a collection of TableValue parameters, filling them up and periodically sending them to the database via a corresponding collection of stored procedures, inside a transaction.

The results are quite satisfying. However, looking at disk usage (% Idle Time in Perfmon), I can see that the disk is getting periodically 'thrashed' (a 'spike' down to 0% every 13-18 seconds), whilst in between the %Idle time is around 90%. I've tried varying the 'batch' size, but it doesn't have an enormous influence.

1. Is this 'normal'? Given that the overall *average* throughput is ok, I could just leave it, but I'm a bit worried about exploding buffers.
2. Should I be able to get better throughput by (somehow) avoiding the spikes while decreasing the overall idle time

[image]

Other details:

- The database is in Simple recovery mode, and pre-sized to 'big', the log file is not growing
- The ldf and mdf files are on different disks (the mdf on a striped array, ldf on a 'normal' disk, all I had available)

Comment: Looks like checkpoints occurring. Any particular reasoning behind this focus on disk idle time? The counters described [in the Accidental DBA series](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/the-accidental-dba-day-21-of-30-essential-perfmon-counters/) are more useful.

Comment: @Mark, not reasoning, just lack of experience!

Comment: Try logging the disk counters in the article I linked and add SQLServer: Buffer Manager: Checkpoint Pages / Sec. Feel free to update the question with the new information.

Comment: That aside, I latched onto the disk idle time because that seemed to correlate with the 'slow downs'.

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith, I think I've found something. For some reason, it's growing the logfile (even if I'm set to SIMPLE mode). I'm using *fairly* small transactions, so I was hoping that would avoid too much log file growth. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd go ahead and set the logfile to a size big enough to accomodate your largest anticipated transactions. Even in simple mode, the transactions are still written to the log, albeit temporarily.  So the translog needs to be at least big enough for one transaction.

Comment: @Bob, the thing is, the longer it runs, the more it grows. Apparently, saving 'in parallel' grows the log file (but overall goes faster), whereas saving 'serially' doesn't. I'm going to test both and post more detailed results here.

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith, new graphic included. I've found out what was growing the log file and reverted it for the moment (saving all tables in parallel).

Comment: Logs can only reset to the last closed transaction - an open tx will keep the log from releasing thigns around it even in simple mode. Ad the spikes are normal - it only is a problem when it hurts you. SQL Server is spiking by design (checkpoints).

Comment: There are faster insert methods. The write characteristics you show point that no minimally logged insert occurs. Read [The Data Loading Performance Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070(v=sql.100).aspx).

Comment: @RemusRusanu, thanks for the heads up. I just tried TABLOCK but it doesn't seem to make my INSERT...SELECT do minimal logging. In fact it seems to be making things worse :(

Comment: This is normal.  Almost every SQL Server I've worked on that did *not* have serious problems looked like this.  I'm pretty sure that this is checkpointing as @TomTom says.

Comment: @Benjol Do you have any unanswered question? Your graphs seem to concur with the original observation that this is checkpoint activity and nothing to worry about.

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith, well Remus seems to imply that I wouldn't get this with minimally logged inserts, so I'm now trying to see if I can get that working, but I guess that is a different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indifferent.

SQL Server batches updates - and especially dirty writes with so called checkpoints. This is pretty much normal behavior and only a problem when it turns into a problem (i.e. too large, slowing down the system etc.)